# Using function .when jQuery in "Javascript"

Tags: jquery, .when

I am new to jQuery `$.When`. I am trying to fill a textbox after another textbox be filling

```
<script>
         var search;
         $.when( search= $("#newhiddenfield").val()).then(myFunc(search)) 

            (function teste(search) {                
                $('.gsc-input').val(search);
                $('.gsc-search-button').click();
            })();  

</script>
```

Comment: You are confusing concepts. $.When has nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve. This pattern is used for different purposes. Maybe you need event listeners: http://jsfiddle.net/8ok26wkv/

Comment: Maybe first of all you should understand `$.when()` and then ask how to do it in javascript..? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve..?

Comment: $.when does not do what you think it does. It will not listen for a variable or input to change, all it does is combine multiple promise objects into one, which has nothing to do with what you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.when` in jquery works with jquery's `Deferred` object (for async behavior).

In your case, DOM operations does not require `when`. You can just write:

```
var search = $("#newhiddenfield").val();

$('.gsc-input').val(search);
$('.gsc-search-button').click();
```